# my pc is using way more RAM than it should

Tags: memory, performance

I have about 6 gb of ram installed, I noticed that the sum of ram usage of all open tasks is way less than what's being in use (about 2.3 gb difference).

[image]

[image]

Is there a problem here? if so how should I fix it?

Edit:

[image]

I couldn't use more than 3gb, everything I opened kept crashing making me restart from square one.

Comment: If you want more information, you need to use the “Details” tab. Of particular interest are the “Memory (active private working set)” and “Commit size” columns. You may have to enable them first.

Comment: Assuming a 64-bit machine, it will use about 4 GB just to be working. So if you have just 6 GB you are probably OK

Comment: RAM doesn't get handed back to the OS unless it's needed for something else. Empty RAM is wasted RAM. Unless you actually have a demonstrable issue… you don't have an issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think that's the case. Until I added a 2gb stick to my pc I would constantly run into memory problems and blue screens of death. what you're saying should be true iff the ram usage stays relatively the same if I open more software and tabs but it doesn't it just keeps increasing

Comment: @DarQ - It absolutely is the case.  Your screenshots don't show all the information.  However, what you have provided, doesn't indicate an actual problem.  You still have 2.2 GB free which is nearly 33% of your memory doing nothing at all.

Comment: More RAM doesn't appear to be needed right now, so it will hang onto it until it is. This is far more efficient than it emtying the RAM for no reason at all, just so you can smile at the numbers. My machine has a lot more RAM, so the numbers get bigger, but right now it using 50GB of 64 total is *absolutely no issue at all*… & incidentally, about the same ⅔ Ramhound mentioned.

Comment: I guess I'll try to recreate some of my earlier problems when using only 4gb because I would constantly reach 100% ram usage while using like 2-2.5gb

Comment: I couldn't use more than 3gb, see edit above

Comment: @Tetsujin, you seem to be thinking of the FS cache, which appears to not be counted in that used figure.  The issue here is that the Windows task manager seems to be lieing about how much ram is being used.  Either it isn't showing all of the ram being used by each process in the process tab, or it is showing way more than is actually being used in the other tab.  Right now the users tab is showing me 4.1 GB used but the performance tab 9.5 GB used ( plus an additional 5.7 GB in the cache ).  Between the kernel paged and non paged pools there's 1.2 GB used there, so where is the missing 4.1 GB